# Visual Studio does not clear error list cache of NewtonSoft JSON errors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

Visual Studio does not consider changes. Initially, I had a few libraries not properly set. Therefore, there were compile time errors. Then I added missing DLLs, and the errors disappeared in the code. However, Visual Studio still says there are errors, and does not allow to build the project.

I tried many ways to handle the problem, none of them was successful.
Already tried ways:

1. ReSharper > Options > General > Clear Cache
2. Tools > C# > Advanced > Enable full solution analysis
3. Deleting .vs folder
4. Clearing VS' temp folder from \AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
5. Restarting Visual Studio
6. Restarting my own machine
7. Clean the solution, project itself
8. Attempt to Rebuild everything
9. Unload/Reload solution and project
10. I hope this will be found here and solve the problem

This is the error I am seing:

[image: Error 'the type or namespace Newtonsoft could not be found']

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I can't build the project. All the errors are still there in the error list

Comment: However, there is no error in the code if I go to those lines where the errors are reported to be

Comment: Hi Davronbek. You should be more specific about the error VS show at compile time. It could be either wrong version of the referenced library or wrong library with an ambiguous namespace. Most likely you are still missing a reference. Try deleting all the DLL references you added and starting over.

Comment: I've experienced a weird case myself: after changing few xamls the solutions doesn't build anymore showing **no errors**. Could be your case, you just don't see that single new error which causes all the others (despite you fix them). The only way to fix was to go through all changes and see if something is clearly wrong.

Comment: Hi, Alex. I have added the picture of the problem for convenience.

Comment: Hi, Sinatr. I have double  checked every line with an error. there is no error in references or in the code. The only problem is that Visual Studio still says that there are errors

Comment: Are you adding Json.net via nuget? If so you may need to remove it (making sure to also remove from packages.config just in-case the entry does not disappear) then re-add fresh.

Comment: Kodaloid, I added Newtonsoft.Json psychically, not via nuget. Because I need only newtonsoft.Json dll and that is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all
The problem was that Newtonsoft.Json Dll I used was for .net 4.5, but the project is in 4.0. Therefore, it did not work properly.

I changed Newtosfot.Json dll .net45 to .net40 and everything is working fine now